# How to run a program on a MacBook Pro with M1 chip at a stable CPU frequency?

Tags: c++, macos, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I am doing an experiment on a C++ program and want to test the program's performance. My laptop is MacBook Pro 21 with M1 Pro chip. Is there any command or method to specify a program run at a specific CPU frequency? Or can I set its performance to run at specific frequency? Is there any command like `cpupower` in linux?

method to set a program at specific CPU frequency

Comment: There are devs on my team who are dealing with this very issue, and how to associate high performance threads to have *affinity* with high performance cores.  I know it is possible, I'm not sure how to do it.  I hope that "knowing it is possible" can be of a tiny bit of help. q.v. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/419787/174758 and https://superuser.com/a/770772/1704263

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm actually not seeking a high performance. I think a stable performance is fine, like CPU frequency running at 1GHz.

Comment: Is your program using 100% of at least one core?  If it is, I would expect it to keep the CPU busy enough to max out the clock speed.  Or do you already have evidence to the contrary?

Comment: How can I bind a process to one specific cpu core and run it at the max clock speed?

Comment: There's something about that [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/44002), although I have to say, after reading it, I'm more confused than I was before.  But this may not be important.  If you do several timing runs on an otherwise quiet machine and they all come up much the same then you've probably measured what you want to measure.  There will probably be some outliers, but you can discard those.

Comment: @XuanZhen what makes you think it’s not running at max performance on one core?

Comment: Basically the performance

Comment: Not necessarily to be max performance, but stable performance should be OK.